# Does Laravel Auth::check() always connect to db to check user?

Tags: laravel

I'm using `Auth::check()` to check user's login status.

Does `Auth::check()` connect to database to perform every login check?

Answer (score 0):

`Auth::check()` verifies that the current session has an authenticated user, either already verified or from the session (which gonna use DB first time) or null.

**Illuminate\Auth\GuardHelpers.php**

```php
**
     * Determine if the current user is authenticated.
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function check()
    {
        return ! is_null($this->user());
    }
```

Example @ **Illuminate\Auth\RequestGuard.php**

```php
/**
     * Get the currently authenticated user.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable|null
     */
    public function user()
    {
        // If we've already retrieved the user for the current request we can just
        // return it back immediately. We do not want to fetch the user data on
        // every call to this method because that would be tremendously slow.
        if (! is_null($this->user)) {
            return $this->user;
        }

        return $this->user = call_user_func(
            $this->callback, $this->request, $this->getProvider()
        );
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of the `RequestGuard`, the default guard is the `SessionGuard`. And yes, the first time you call `Auth::check()`, it will perform one database lookup to check for the currently logged in User.

After that, every consecutive call in the same request will not perform another database lookup.

Answer (score -1):

The `check()` method do this:

```
/**
 * Determine if the current user is authenticated.
 *
 * @return bool
 */
public function check()
{
    return ! is_null($this->user());
}
```

Now, the interesting part is what the `user()` method does. You can see it in detail and well explained [in the source code](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/6.x/src/Illuminate/Auth/SessionGuard.php#L121):

> ```
> public function user()
> {
>     if ($this->loggedOut) {
>         return;
>     }
>
>     // If we've already retrieved the user for the current request we can just
>     // return it back immediately. We do not want to fetch the user data on
>     // every call to this method because that would be tremendously slow.
>     if (! is_null($this->user)) {
>         return $this->user;
>     }
>
>     $id = $this->session->get($this->getName());
>
>     // First we will try to load the user using the identifier in the session if
>     // one exists. Otherwise we will check for a "remember me" cookie in this
>     // request, and if one exists, attempt to retrieve the user using that.
>     if (! is_null($id) && $this->user = $this->provider->retrieveById($id)) {
>         $this->fireAuthenticatedEvent($this->user);
>     }
>
>     // If the user is null, but we decrypt a "recaller" cookie we can attempt to
>     // pull the user data on that cookie which serves as a remember cookie on
>     // the application. Once we have a user we can return it to the caller.
>     if (is_null($this->user) && ! is_null($recaller = $this->recaller())) {
>         $this->user = $this->userFromRecaller($recaller);
>
>         if ($this->user) {
>             $this->updateSession($this->user->getAuthIdentifier());
>
>             $this->fireLoginEvent($this->user, true);
>         }
>     }
>
>     return $this->user;
> }
> ```

Comment: Why is this downvoted? It responds the OP's question. And, in case of an observation, why not leave also a comment?